# Why is it said that we dont need to clone an immutable class?

Tags: java, clone, immutability

An immutable class is simply a class whose instances cannot be modified. Immutable class is good for caching purpose and it is thread safe. Immutable objects are instances whose states do not change once initiated.

Whereas, Object cloning refers to creation of exact copy of an object. It creates a new instance of the class of current object and initializes all its fields with exactly the contents of the corresponding fields of this object.

Now, the question arises, why is it said that we don't need to clone an immutable class?

*Is it because creating exact copies of the data which is already used for caching purposes will add to the garbage created in the system and potentially slow down the application.* Or some other relevant answer lies within?

Comment: You can always use the same object for your purpose since you are assured of immutability , hence no side effects.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you already have an object of an immutable class, there's no point in having a second functionally identical one also, you can just use the one instance everywhere. Also if would you clone it, you would just use twice as much memory for no extra gain.

Comment: Exactly my point, that the identical object will not serve any purpose and only lead to heavy garbage collection.

Comment: It's not a nitpick but a crucial distinction to emphasize that the objects are **not** "identical". They are (or should usually be) *equal*. In Java, this means that basically for `Person p0 = new Person("Jon"); Person p1 = new Person("Jon");` the comparison `p0 == p1` will yield `false` (because the objects are not identical), wheras `p0.equals(p1)` should yield `true` (assuming a proper `equals` implemenation).

Comment: @Marco13 Yes true, specified it a bit.

Answer (score 8):

You usually create copies (clones) of an object if you want to make changes in the state of the copy without changing the state of the original object.

Since the state of objects of immutable classes cannot be changed, you can use the original object without any risk of changing its state.